# Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, h2

I've just started to learn Spring. While I am trying to program taco-cloud app in Spring in Action book, I am getting "No identifier specified for entity" error. In chapter 3, I am trying to learn JPA using H2 database.

My Order model:

```
package com.example.tacocloud.models;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Taco_Order")
public class Order implements Serializable {

    ...

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private Date placedAt;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity=Taco.class)
    private List<Taco> tacos = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addDesign(Taco design) {
        this.tacos.add(design);
    }

    @PrePersist
    void placedAt() {
        this.placedAt = new Date();
    }

}
```

and my Ingredient.class looks like this:

```
package com.example.tacocloud.models;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access= AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force=true)
@Entity // if I change it to Embedded I get unmapped ManyToMany error in my Ingredient class.

public class Ingredient {
    private final String id;
    private final String name;
    private final Type type;

    public static enum Type{
        WRAP, PROTEIN, VEGGIES, CHEESE, SAUCE
    }
}
```

and my taco class:

```
package com.example.tacocloud.models;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
public class Taco {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private Date createdAt;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=5, message="Name must be at least 5 characters long")
    private  String name;
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity=Ingredient.class)
    @Size(min=1, message="You must choose at least 1 ingredient")
    private List<String> ingredients;

    @PrePersist
    void createdAt() {
        this.createdAt = new Date();
    }
}
```

and my sql files :

```
delete from Taco_Order_Tacos;
delete from Taco_Ingredients;
delete from Taco;
delete from Taco_Order;
delete from Ingredient;
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type)
                values ('FLTO', 'Flour Tortilla', 'WRAP');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type)
                values ('COTO', 'Corn Tortilla', 'WRAP');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type)
                values ('GRBF', 'Ground Beef', 'PROTEIN');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type)
                values ('CARN', 'Carnitas', 'PROTEIN');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type)
                values ('TMTO', 'Diced Tomatoes', 'VEGGIES');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type)
                values ('LETC', 'Lettuce', 'VEGGIES');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type)
                values ('CHED', 'Cheddar', 'CHEESE');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type)
                values ('JACK', 'Monterrey Jack', 'CHEESE');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type)
                values ('SLSA', 'Salsa', 'SAUCE');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type)
                values ('SRCR', 'Sour Cream', 'SAUCE');
```

schema.sql:

```
create table if not exists Ingredient (
  id varchar(4) not null,
  name varchar(25) not null,
  type varchar(10) not null
);
create table if not exists Taco (
  id identity,
  name varchar(50) not null,
  createdAt timestamp not null
);
create table if not exists Taco_Ingredients (
  taco bigint not null,
  ingredient varchar(4) not null
);
alter table Taco_Ingredients
    add foreign key (taco) references Taco(id);
alter table Taco_Ingredients
    add foreign key (ingredient) references Ingredient(id);
create table if not exists Taco_Order (
  id identity,
    deliveryName varchar(50) not null,
    deliveryStreet varchar(50) not null,
    deliveryCity varchar(50) not null,
    deliveryState varchar(2) not null,
    deliveryZip varchar(10) not null,
    ccNumber varchar(16) not null,
    ccExpiration varchar(5) not null,
    ccCVV varchar(3) not null,
    placedAt timestamp not null
);
create table if not exists Taco_Order_Tacos (
  tacoOrder bigint not null,
  taco bigint not null
);
alter table Taco_Order_Tacos
    add foreign key (tacoOrder) references Taco_Order(id);
alter table Taco_Order_Tacos
    add foreign key (taco) references Taco(id);
```

btw my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `Ingredient` has no `@Id` field plus it is a class of immutable objects which is not appropriate for a serialization class - you must have default constructor like every other class has. Remove `@NoArgsConstructor(access= AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force=true)` it is very strange and can confuse your frameworks